# String interpolation does not work properly on my XML if there is navigation happens inside of my NativeScript Angular app

Tags: xml, angular, angular2-routing, nativescript, string-interpolation

**Please watch this gif as it describes the problem more efficiently! http://recordit.co/9BvtwWNAYZ**

My project is huge by far so I will cut to the point:

I am making a login and a registration page for my NativeScript Angular Mobile app.

The registration page simply looks like

[image]

And it works like, if the input email is not found in the database, it can ask the user to directly go to the registration page:

[image]

As you see here I am using FancyAlertButtons, and there's an option called "Register as a new user", and that will direct to the registration page. The code behind the scene is

```
//inside of login.component.ts
public login(){
    if (this.email && this.password){
        if (this.password.match()) {
            // User found, log the user in
        } else {
            console.log("User has not registered.");
            let userNotFoundButtons = [
                new TNSFancyAlertButton({ label: 'Register As A New User', action: () => { this.router.navigate(["register"]); } }),
                new TNSFancyAlertButton({ label: 'Continue As Guest.', action: () => { this.router.navigate(["guest"]); } }),
                new TNSFancyAlertButton({ label: 'Try Logging In Again.', action: () => { } }),
            ];
            TNSFancyAlert.showCustomButtons(userNotFoundButtons, this.logoImageAddress, "#d11717", 'You have not registered!', 'Would you like to?', 'Ok');
    } else {
        (new SnackBar()).simple("Both fields are required!");
    }
}
```

In above code block, this line of code does the navigation

```
new TNSFancyAlertButton({ label: 'Register As A New User', action: () => { this.router.navigate(["register"]); } }),
```

Then the registration page looks like,

[image]

And after the user has filled in the form（in the picture I have pre-filled the form for the later description purpose) and hit register, it will jump to a simple welcome page, which **SHOULD LOOK LIKE:**

[image: Picture4]
Picture4

BUT Instead, it gives me:

[image]

Code in my loggedIn.component.ts and loggedIn.component.html (the welcome page) are:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "application-settings";

@Component({
    selector: "logged-in",
    templateUrl: "./components/functionalPages/loggedIn.component.html",
})

export class LoggedInComponent implements OnInit{

    public firstname: string;
    public lastname: string;
    public email: string;
    public companyName: string;
    public phone: string;
    public ccNumber: string;

    public constructor(){

        this.firstname = "";
        this.lastname = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.companyName = "";
        this.phone = "";
        this.ccNumber = "";

        // This is called because at first I found that ngOnInit() wouldn't get called
        // after clicking the Sign Up button if we navigate the user to sign up on the log in page
        // but turns out it's not the solution
        this.ngOnInit();
    }

    public ngOnInit(){
        this.firstname = ApplicationSettings.getString("firstname");
        this.lastname = ApplicationSettings.getString("lastname");
        this.email = ApplicationSettings.getString("email");
        this.companyName = ApplicationSettings.getString("companyName");
        this.phone = ApplicationSettings.getString("phone");
        this.ccNumber = ApplicationSettings.getString("ccNumber");

        console.log(this.firstname);
        // and this consolo.log() gives me the correct firstname value
    }

}
```

and

```
<ActionBar title="I'm In!"></ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Welcome!"></Label>
            <Label text="My name is {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }} with email address {{ email }}. I'm from {{ companyName }} and my phone is {{ phone }} and ccNumber is {{ ccNumber }}." textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

The problem is, the consolo.log(this.firstname) has given me the correct value, but on the UI it just doesn't display anything.

HOWEVER, if I directly register the user by clicking the "Register" button on the home page(also the login page), after signing up, the user info can be displayed properly as it's shown in picture4 above. Also, if I now log in the user on the log in page, the info can be displayed as well. **Actually, picture4 is created when I go back to the login page and directly logging in for@stackoverflow.testing. You can easily get my idea by watching this gif http://recordit.co/9BvtwWNAYZ**

My question:

**How this navigation makes the values impossible to be displayed and how to solve it? Plus, why ngOnInit() wouldn't get called neither if I used navigation here?**

What I have tried:

```
this.zone.run()
this.location.subscribe()
this.router.events.subscribe()
```

all not work.

Thanks in advance, and please advise if there's anything unclear or you demand more code from other files.

**Please watch this gif as it describes the problem more efficiently! http://recordit.co/9BvtwWNAYZ**

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're specifying your `label` text with a `text` attribute, rather than just putting the text between tags like this: `<label>Text here</label>`?

Comment: @kshetline Thanks for your comment. No there's no particular reason. I just learned to do in that way rather than putting the text in between. Could it be the reason??

Comment: I'd at least give moving the text a try. I'm kind of surprised it even works for the "Welcome!" message.

Comment: @kshetline just tried by changing it to `<ActionBar title="I'm In!"></ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
 <Label text="Welcome!"></Label>
            <Label textWrap="true">My name is {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }} with email address {{ email }}. I'm from {{ companyName }} and my phone is {{ phone }} and ccNumber is {{ ccNumber }}.</Label>
</StackLayout>`, still doesn't work, and it even won't work for direct registration! Is there anything I do wrong? And yeah, text attribute could be used in that way ;)

Comment: kshetline we are talking about NativeScript and using the `text` property is the way to go - you can add text within the tags in NativeScript

Comment: Try using binding for example  `<Label [text]="firstname + ' some string to concatanete here ' + lastname"`

Comment: @NickIliev Thanks! I've tried property binding actually, and it didn't work either :( this is really weird!

Comment: The code seems OK but I guess it has something to with the plugin - if you could provide a sample project to debug it would be great - you can contact me in the NativeScript community slack - username: niliev  https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/messages/general

Comment: @NickIliev Hi Nick sorry I just saw your reply and thanks for your generous help! Yea definitely I will try to shorten my project to the point and provide the sample code when I get home. Much appreciate it! :D